# How to loop through an array of integers in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 SQL tables:

- The first one: contains Codes [1 .. 22] and each code represents a value. This list is always fixed (no changes on it) - I am going to call the column **Code1**
- The second one contains also contains Codes, and each time we use a set of codes and each code represents a value - I am going to call the column **Code2**
- The third table has 2 columns (2 FKs) **Code1|Code2** coming from the previous tables

My question is I want to iterate always through all of the values of Code1 column from the first table (no matter how many codes I have) and for a certain/specific values of Code2 column from the second table, let's say [30.. 55]. I want to insert the Code1 and Code2 into the third table.

Example:

```
Table 1
Code1|Descript
1|A
2|B
3|C

Table 2
Code2|Descript
1|AA
2|BB
3|CC
4|DD
5|EE
```

I want to insert into my third table the following values

```
Table 3
Code1|Code2
1|2
1|3
1|4
2|2
2|3
2|4
3|2
3|3
3|4
```

Basically looping through every value from Table 1 and for specific values from Table 2 (in my example [2,3, 4]), I made the insert queries

What is the optimal way to do those insert queries without having to create an insert query for every single entry?

My solution is something like the following:

```
INSERT INTO T3 
   SELECT T1.Code1, T2.Code2
   FROM T1 CROSS JOIN (
       SELECT Code2
       FROM T2
       WHERE Code2 BETWEEN x and y)T2
```

Thanks,

Comment: First, SQL Server has no concept of "arrays", so I don't understand the question.  Second, you seem to be suggesting that you are storing multiple values in a string column.  That just means that you have a broken data model.  Fix it.

Comment: Do a `JOIN`, but I need to see a better description of the data to say what that join looks like.

Comment: That's true Gordon.. The way I put my question relates more to my programming background. The data base is fine and normalized

Comment: Please share some sample data from these three tables and your desired results after this process runs. Your question is confusing since you are using terminology that doesn't fit well with rdbms. I agree with @Riad that this is a simple INSERT using a join and WHERE clause, but some sample and desired results would help a ton.

Comment: I will edit my question. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE3 (code1, code2) 
     SELECT 
           T1.Code1, T2.Code2 
               FROM Table1 T1 JOIN Table2 T2
               ON T2.code2 IN(2,3,4)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Cato for the answer, the solution that I wrote does not have join but this seems to be better.

Answer (score 0):

An INSERT statement where we cross join the two tables (Selecting the range in the second table you are after) should do the trick here:

```
INSERT INTO table3
SELECT table1.code1, table2.code2
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table2.code2 BETWEEN 2 and 4
```

If you don't want duplicates hitting `table3` should the relationship already exist then you can do something like:

```
INSERT INTO table3
SELECT table1.code1, table2.code2
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table2.code2 BETWEEN 2 and 4
   AND (table1.code1, table2.code2) NOT IN (SELECT code1, code2 FROM table3)
```

Comment: Thank you @JNevill for your answer. Yes, I had the same solution but I missed the idea behind your second query. This helped me understand it better

Answer (score 0):

I think query needs to be cross join as you need all rows from first table paired with certain rows in second table

```
INSERT INTO TABLE3 (code1, code2) 
     SELECT 
           T1.Code1, T2.Code2 
               FROM Table1 T1 CROSS JOIN Table2 T2
               ON T2.code2 IN(2,3,4)
```

Comment: Indeed, Thank you Dee P

Comment: do you use 'ON' with 'CROSS JOIN'?   I thought you had to use WHERE

Comment: Yes @Cato
`INSERT INTO TABLE3 (code1, code2) 
     SELECT 
           T1.Code1, T2.Code2 
               FROM Table1 T1 CROSS JOIN Table2 T2
               WHERE T2.code2 IN(2,3,4)`